# Calculus Initial Value Separable Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the problem and my steps, I'm not sure if I did it right or not. Thanks for the help:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=exp(x+y); y(0)=1$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=e^{x+y}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=e^xe^y$$
$$e^ydy=\frac{1}{e^x}dx$$
$$\int{e^ydy}=\int{\frac{1}{e^x}dx}$$
$$e^y=x+C$$
$$e^1=0+C$$
$$C=e$$
$$y=ln\left | x+e\right |$$

Answer (score 2):

$\int{\frac{1}{e^x}dx}=\int{e^{-x}dx}=-e^{-x}$

Comment: So then would my answer be $y=ln\left |-e^{-x}+e+1 \right |$?

Comment: You'd have $e^{-x}+e^y=C$. Applying initial conditions $C=e+1$

Comment: Yes, you're right.